# Debugging Web App running ASP.NET 4.7.1 Website cannot be reached

Tags: azure

I have published a website running on `Asp.Net 4.7.1` to `Azure` from `Visual Studio`.

The site has published successfully and I can verify the files have successfully being added to the `Azure Web App` through the Kudo explorer.

However, when i navigate to the .azurewebsite.net url to view the site, I am getting a `site cannot be reached error`.

[image: azure screenshot of webapp]

I have set the `App Service Logs` to be verbose. Below is a screen shot of the `Log Stream`

[image: azure log stream]

Comment: seems to be some missing setting. Enable log stream and search for some error.

Comment: thanks for the comment I have updated the question with the verbose log stream. Does this help?

Comment: no errors in the log..have you access the page when you took this screenshot?

Comment: Yes I have and refreshed too. However I still get the error that the website cannot be reached.